# How to filter the List using C# LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of Elements. I need to get all the elements with a filter on each attribute where Category name is "XYZ".

The follow query definitely does a filter on attributes to select the attributes with category name "XYZ", but I want the element details of these filtered attributes as well.

```
var filteredAttributes = attributes.Where(at => at.Categories.Any(ca => ca.Name == "XYZ")).Any()).ToList();
```

But if I do the same filter on elements, I get all elements without a filter on attributes.  **Is it possible to create a one-line query to filter on elements to grab the necessary attributes?**

This is the LINQ query I tried which fails:

```
var filteredElements = elements.Where(el => el.attributes.Where(at => at.Categories.Any(ca => ca.Name == "Alarm")).Any()).ToList();
```

Here are the classes defined:

```
public class Element
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public Boolean HasChildren { get; set; }
    public List<Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }
}
    public class Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string WebID { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What you mean by "fails"? Exception throw or not expected result?

Comment: Why are you limiting to one-line lambdas? You may hinder readability and maintainability in doing so.

Comment: Isn't is like `var filteredElements = elements.Where(el => el.attributes.Any(ca => ca.Name == "Alarm"))` ?

Comment: @Fabio not sure why you removed your answer... I didn't agree with the criticism about it OP wrote "but I want the element details of these filtered attributes as well."

Comment: Your code examples have unmatched parentheses.  I think it's possible to do what you want, I just can't figure out what that is.

Comment: Your query fails as `Where` looks for a predicate and you are supplying it with an `IEnumerable` and later on applying `Any`, which is somehow not a correct usage

Answer (score 1):

Just put your first query inside `Where` of `elements`
I think it will be enough to use `Any` on attributes with inner `Any` on categories

```
var filteredElements = 
    elements.Where(el => 
    {
        return el.attributes.Any(at => at.Categories.Any(ca => ca.Name.Equals("Alarm")));
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: That's functionally equivalent to the first example OP provided as the `Any()` will accept the `Where()` filter and behave the same.

Comment: @krillgar in the first example OP wrote the ements are missing... it looks like elements are parents of attributes... OP should clarify

Comment: @Fabio- I tried the same thing. It doesn't work. Your solution is same as 

elements.Where(el => el.attributes.Where(at => at.Categories.Any(ca => ca.Name == "Alarm")).Any()).ToList();

Comment: @Fabio - It basically returns the entire list without any filter

Comment: @Ramji, I afraid you need check that collection actually contains `Category` with name "Alarm"